# Why does this script-fu not work?

Tags: lisp, scheme, gimp, script-fu

```
(define (script-fu-create-camo image colA colB))

(script-fu-register
    "script-fu-create-camo"
    "Camoflauge"
    "Creates a camoflauge pattern on an image"
    "Jeffrey Aylesworth <jeffrey@aylesworth"
    "Copyright (c) 2009 Jeffrey Aylesworth"
    "2009/12/31"
    ""

    SF-IMAGE "Image" 0
    SF-COLOR "Colour 1" '(50 0 0)
    SF-COLOR "Colour 2" '(0 50 0))

(script-fu-menu-register "script-fu-create-camo" "<Image>/Filters/Render")
```

I am using Gimp 2.6 on Mac OS 10.6. The script is saved as `~/gimp-2.6/scripts/camoflauge.scm`, the script does not create a new item in the menu. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a few script-fu scripts which I used on my mac. I always placed them in:

```
/Applications/Gimp.app/Content/Resources/share/Gimp/2.0/scripts/
```

And on my register I would prepend the `"<Image>/Filters/Render"` with an underscore, so `_"<Image>/Filters/Render"`

Hope this helps, been a while since I was messing with this.

Comment: I'd rather not keep them inside the app, but I will give that a try later. Also, what does the underscore mean in front of a string?

Comment: Damn you for making me think on New Year's Eve! I don't know why I use the underscore, but all my scripts have it. I had to boot up my mac and test it without the underscore and it doesn't appear to make a difference. That makes me feel silly. If I had to guess I would say your issue is that the directory you are placing the .scm in is not in your folders list (Edit->Preferences->Folders->Scripts).

Comment: That's weird, I guess it's just a style thing then. Putting it in the application fixed it, and looking at the preferences, it wants to use `~/Library/Application Support/Gimp/scripts/`, thanks for the help!